# Selenium Java - How to set desktop background from Firefox?

Tags: java, selenium

this is my first question.

I am new at Selenium and I am trying a simple example of automation. What I want to do, as the title says, is to:

-Open Firefox> go to an image link> right click on the image> go to "Set as background" option (click on it)> and finally click "Set background" on the pop-up that appears.

In the last step is my problem, I have done all the steps but when the confirmation pop-up or emergent window (I don't know what it is) appears I cannot click on the button or send an ENTER key.

Here is my code:

```
public class firstSteps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, firefoxProfile);
    driver.get("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpapers-for-Background-HD-Wallpaper-1080x607.jpg");
    //Right click 
    Actions rClick = new Actions(driver);
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);
    rClick.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html//body//img"))).build().perform();
    //Move through menu
    rClick.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
    rClick.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
    rClick.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
    rClick.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
    rClick.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
    //Select option
    rClick.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    //Here I should click on that option
}
```

}

I've tried to move through new tab and send ENTER key and also just sending the ENTER key because both work when doing it manually but none has worked.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Can you debug and share what is happening? It's hard to suggest changes based on "none has worked"

Comment: When I run this code it just opens the browser, goes to the image link, right click on it and select the "Set as background" option. After this a windows appears and I don't know how to manage it because I do not know if it is a window or a pop-up.